# Is there a R function to compare the frequency of occurrences of row elements between two dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, frequency

Say I have two dataframes

```
df1
Var1=c("a", "b", "c")
Freq= c(1, 3, 8)

df2
Var1= c("a", "b", "c")
Freq= c(5, 3, 8)
```

so I want my output to be y & z as their frequencies match between the two dataframes.

Comment: can you share reproducible example using dput(df1) and dput(df2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
#Code
df1$Var1[df1$Freq==df2$Freq]
```

Output:

```
[1] "y" "z"
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("x", "y", "z"), Freq = c(1L, 3L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("x", "y", "z"), Freq = c(5L, 3L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
> df1
  Var1 Freq
1    x    1
2    y    3
3    z    8
> df2
  Var1 Freq
1    x    5
2    y    3
3    z    8
> df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = c('Var1' = 'Var1', 'Freq' = 'Freq' )) %>% pull(1)
[1] "y" "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `with`

```
with(df1, Var1[Freq == df2$Freq])
#[1] "y" "z"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("x", "y", "z"), Freq = c(1L, 3L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


df2 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("x", "y", "z"), Freq = c(5L, 3L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```